# How to transform multiple dataframe columns into one numpy array column

Tags: numpy, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf,SQLContext
import numpy as np

config = SparkConf("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=config)
sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("doc_3",1,3,9), ("doc_1",9,6,0), ("doc_2",9,9,3) ]).withColumnRenamed("_1","doc").withColumnRenamed("_2","word1").withColumnRenamed("_3","word2").withColumnRenamed("_4","word3")
```

Now I need to keep the first column and the rest columns as a numpy array (two columns : "doc" and a numpy array column)

I know that

```
sdf=np.array(df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in {'doc'}]).collect())
print sdf
```

Translate all the columns into a numpy array but how do I append the numpy array with the first column ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot make `numpy.array` column in pyspark dataframe, but you can use regular `python` list instead, and convert it while reading:

```py
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("doc_3",[1,3,9]), ("doc_1",[9,6,0]), ("doc_2",[9,9,3]) ]).withColumnRenamed("_1","doc").withColumnRenamed("_2","words")
>>> df.show()
+-----+---------+
|  doc|    words|
+-----+---------+
|doc_3|[1, 3, 9]|
|doc_1|[9, 6, 0]|
|doc_2|[9, 9, 3]|
+-----+---------+

>>> df
DataFrame[doc: string, words: array<bigint>]
```

And to get this from 4 columns you had, you can:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df2=df.select("doc", array("word1", "word2", "word3").alias("words"))
>>> df2
DataFrame[doc: string, words: array<bigint>]
>>> df2.show()
+-----+---------+
|  doc|    words|
+-----+---------+
|doc_3|[1, 3, 9]|
|doc_1|[9, 6, 0]|
|doc_2|[9, 9, 3]|
+-----+---------+
```